# TableView inside Navigation Controller: Zero Edge Insets on the Left and on the Right?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, insets, uiedgeinsets

I have got a TableView inside a Navigation Controller.

By default, the TableView has edge insets set on the left and on the right. That is, the content's width in the TableView is smaller than iPhone width.

My designer wants me to have the content stretched from left to right on the iPhone without any insets.

So, I tried the following code:

```
UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 10);
tableView.contentInset = inset;
```

On the left, the content is now really at the iPhone left edge. Fine. It worked.

But on the right, no setting seems to move the content to the right.

Your help is much appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use this  UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, -10);
tableView.contentInset = inset;

Comment: It does not work. The last value has no effect whatsoever. It does not change anything regardless of the value.

Comment: btw is it a plain or group table?

Comment: it is a plain table, no groups.

Comment: One way is to override the cell.contentView layoutSubViews by subclassing the TableViewCell. Let me what are the contents inside TableViewcell you are using.

Comment: Try setting tableview.frame with extra +10 width added after setting tableView.contentInset.

Comment: @PratikMistry I think it won't work, because we have to override the autolayout for the contents for the Cell.contentView

Answer (score 0):

The Clean Solution would be

Subclass the UITableViewCell class, and override the layoutSubViews method like the following.

And also set tableView contentInsets to zero.

```
mTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

-(void)layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.textLabel.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The last value has no effect whatsoever. It does not change anything regardless of the value.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. If I subclass the UITableViewCell class, do I have to put all the elements of my cell (custom ones) into it and then add the subclassed cell to the table view?

Comment: @user1006117 Let me know what are the other elements you need to implement on the TableViewCell. Yeah, if you need custom elements, you have to add them as subviews, and also updated their frames in LayoutSubViews method.

Comment: I have got an image on the left and an image on the right. Then I have color customization of the text and background.

Comment: @user1006117 So you are already using the TableViewCell subclass? If yes, just make sure your subViews frames are properly set. We can solve this quickly if you can reach me on my email.

Comment: no, at the moment I am just customizing the cell in (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: It does not work. In that method, I am now doing  `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;          cell.textLabel.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
cell.textLabel.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;` And it still simply does not work :)

Comment: Now that I created a custom cell and it still does not work :)

Comment: I think, the problem is nothing to do with tableview but probably with scrollview that is added automatically?

Comment: TableView is the subclass of ScrollView. It is working for me. Subclass the tableViewCell and override layoutsubviews